# Can I run perl unit tests under ant jUnit task? How can I handle perl unit tests errors within ant build script?

Tags: perl, ant, junit, testing, tap

I'd like to deploy my set of perl scripts by ant.

I'm going to run perl test scripts in the ant build.xml and I want to handle perl errors.

That's why I wonder, how does  ant task work?

Does junit parse output of tests?

In this case I can transform TAP output within TAP::Formatter::JUnit CPAN module.

http://search.cpan.org/dist/TAP-Formatter-JUnit/lib/TAP/Formatter/JUnit.pm

Or, may be,  ant task handles some system messages.

In this case I will not be able to conjugate perl testing and junit handling.

To say simplier, how can I "implant" perl module installing procedure (I use Module::Build) into my Apache Ant build script to handle perl tests errors?

Answer (score 0):

The testing step returns a non-zero exit code if it failed.